# Creating a Batch (.bat) file to open multiple CMD windows each pinging different sites

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-10, multiple-instances

I have a funny problem. I frequently have to open up CMD windows to communicate to offsite offices to see if their internet is up. For this example I'll just use 2 generic places. For the Code I have so far, it doesn't seem to work like it should based on what I've researched. It continues to open these two CMD Windows over and over without closing any of the prior ones and will continue to do this "open cmd" loop until either the computer crashes or the account is signed out, or the machine is restarted/hard reset.

```
start cmd /k ping 8.8.8.8 -t
start cmd /k ping google.com -t
```

or I have also tried

```
start cmd /k ping 8.8.8.8 -t & start ping google.com -t
```

The last one I heard "could" work for creating the two separate windows, which it did, but same "never-ending" loop of opening them commenced.

All I want out of the batch file is to open a CMD Window each with its own designated site to ping without it continually opening the same CMD windows over and over until oblivion.

Lastly, for potential important details, I have a Windows 10 Pro machine with plenty of ram (it can take a while for my computer to crash from these cmd windows but its nearly impossible to stop them.) And I have seen this exact same issue occur on a Windows 7 Enterprise and Pro Editions as well. Not sure if this really has anything to do with it. However it seems that everyone I have researched doesn't seem to have a problem running the above code and getting never ending CMD Windows opening up. Maybe its a execution setting set somewhere in a GPO or hidden CMD settings I've got to change permissions wise?

Comment: Don't call your batch file ping.

Comment: If you're using the `/K` option and not `Exit`ing what did you expect to happen with those opened `cmd` windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to elaborate on @ACatInLove comment which is the correct answer.  The cmd interpreter/window will run a command or batch that matches the name in the current folder first and then search in the path.

Imagine I have an executable `test.exe` installed somewhere on my computer.  Then I have a batch file `test.bat` in my current folder which is supposed to call `test` the executable.  By running test it will infinitely run the batch file test.

My test.bat is as follows:

```
test -parameters
pause
```

There are two solutions:

1. Call the batch file something else like `SuperTest.bat`
2. Execute the command using `test.exe` which will not then match a batch file.

Comment: Thanks miltonb, for the elaboration! I definitely agree that @ACatInLove 's comment is correct, and I felt quite dumb after they mentioned that, because suddenly it all made sense. I forgot that Windows has a "ping.exe" and after making sure to name it something other than a .exe as you elaborated on, it worked without creating the multiple instances. I really don't know why I didn't notice that sooner, but it did give a good laugh and is quite hilarious now. I would mark ACatInLove's comment as the correct answer, but I don't see how I can, so I will mark yours as the Correct Answer.

Comment: Its a VERY common problem. It really doesn't deserve an *answer*.